# Locust login testing on Laravel app

Tags: php, python, laravel, locust

Trying to login to laravel application using Locust.
My code is following:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
  def on_start(self):
    self.login()

  def login(self):
    response = self.client.get("/en/login")
    csrftoken = response.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']
    session = response.cookies['bitrent_session']
    post_data = {'username': "user@user.com", 'password': '1234', "_token":     csrftoken }
    with self.client.post('/en/login', post_data,
                    catch_response=True) as response:
      print("Code: ", response.status_code)
      print("Content: ", response.content

  @task()
  def index(self):
    self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
  task_set = UserBehavior
  min_wait = 5000
  max_wait = 9000
```

However I got error - Code 419 Content The page has expired due to inactivity.
Could anyone advise me how to login to Laravel application using Locust

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer:

Reason is that I'm passing wrong value for _token field.
Instead, if you face same task, you could try following:

```
import re
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
  def on_start(self):
    self.login()

  def login(self):
    response = self.client.get("/en/login")
    print("Content: ", response.content)
    csrftoken = re.search('meta name="csrf-token" content="(.+?)"', response.text).group(1)

    print("token: ", csrftoken)
    post_data = {'username': "user@user.com", 'password': '1234', "_token": csrftoken }
    with self.client.post('/en/login', post_data,
                catch_response=True) as response:
      print("Code: ", response.status_code)
      print("Content: ", response.content)


  @task()
  def index(self):
    self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
  task_set = UserBehavior
  min_wait = 5000
  max_wait = 9000
```

Hope that will help someone in future :)