# locust login testing on laravel app with inertia/vue breeze

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, locust

I am load testing a laravel application with Locust.

This reference: [Locust login testing on Laravel app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311068/locust-login-testing-on-laravel-app)

describes how to login; however, that is using blade templates and the application I am working with utilizes interia with vue and the authentication package breeze.

The meta token "csrf-token" is not available to pass along.

Logging in is an API post request in JSON format.

I've attempted to pass in the cookies and headers; however, I continue to get a 419 response (page expired).

Including some rudimentary python code (that is outside of locust - just trying to login via requests)

```
import requests
import json


#get cookies
r1 = requests.get('https://myurl.com/login')
print(f"Status Code: {r1.status_code}")
csrftoken = r1.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']
session = r1.cookies['nexus_session']
print(f'csrftoken: {csrftoken}')
print(f'session: {session}')


post = {
    'email': "myemail@email.com", 
    'password': 'password'
}

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN" : csrftoken,
    'Host': 'myurl.com',
    'Origin': 'https://myurl.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'https://myurl.com/login',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0',
    'X-Inertia': 'true',
    'X-Inertia-Version': 'c575a239ca3c6c444d8629dbd0639df5',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

r = requests.post('https://myurl.com/login', json=post, headers=headers, cookies=r1.cookies)

print(f"Status Code: {r.status_code}")
```